# Using a provider in a custom class flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a program that needs to use Provider to get values. I call my provider like below in a stateful widget

```
final user = Provider.of<Users>(context);
```

Now I would like to use the provider in a custom class

```
class UserInformation {
    final user = Provider.of<Users>(context):
}
```

This won't work because context is not defined. kindly assist on how I can do this without using a `BuildContext`.

This is my class Users that I have on a separate dart file and use as a model for for my data streams.

```
class Users {
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String department;
  final String position;

  Users({ this.uid, this.department, this.name, this.position });
}
```

This is the query I use to pull data from firestore

```
Stream<List<FormQuestions>> get userData{
  return userCollection.where('name', isEqualTo: 'First Name').where('department', isEqualTo: 'department').snapshots()
  .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
}
```

I would like the name to be a variable that I get from say (user.name) from the model class. and the same for the department.

Thanks.

Comment: Is UserInformation a widget?

Comment: It is a class that I am using for all my database querries

Answer (score 4):

You can only access classes which are `ChangeNotifiers` in the descendant widgets in the tree below this provided `ChangeNotifier` because behind the scenes the `Provider` uses `InheritedWidget` (which uses `context`) to provide you with the `ChangeNotifier` you put up in the tree

So in your case there is no way to access the `Users` from `UserInformation` and you have to alter your code to make a workaround

**Edit:** this is a suggestion to achieve what you want **if** you are using this code inside a widget:

```
class UserInformation{
  final User user;

  UserInformation(this.user);
}

class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeWidgetState createState() => _SomeWidgetState();
}

class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {

  void someMethod(){
    final User user = Provider.of<Users>(context);
    UserInformation userInformation = UserInformation(user);
    //do something
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¡Hey! In the class you need to add "with ChangeNotifier":

```
    class Users with ChangeNotifier {
      final String uid;
      final String name;
      final String department;
      final String position;

      Users({ this.uid, this.department, this.name, this.position });
    }
```

Hope help. Sorry for the english, yo hablo español. :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).